# Why does my int function get the warning: control reaches end of non-void function?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return

I have a function `Largest` that accepts three parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`. The function aims to return the largest value of the three inputs. However, I encountered an error when I compiled my code stating that the function may not return a value. I'm unsure why this error occurred since I am indeed returning a value in the function.

Below is my code in C++:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

int Largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a > b && a > c) {  
        return a;
    }
    else if (a < b && b > c) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (a < c && c > b) {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Any help understanding and resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your function return if all three values are equal?

Comment: What will `Largest(0, 0, 0)` return?

Comment: *since I am indeed returning a value in the function.* -- [That is not entirely true](https://godbolt.org/z/89z1Whz7P).  Do you see the "Oops" message being printed?  That could have only happened if the `std::cout` line was invoked, and you see where that line of code is.

Comment: *"I'm unsure why this error occurred"* -- Perhaps you are thinking in absolutes? A key word in the error message is "may" -- the error is not saying that the function *never* returns a value. It is consistent for a function both to contain a `return` statement and to sometimes not execute any `return` statements.

Comment: A general approach to this kind of thing is to work in stages: `int result = a; if (b > result) result = b; if (c > result) result = c; return result;`. This is also much easier to read than all those conditionals with `>` and `<` running around.

Answer (score 6):

Consider a case like this:

```cpp
int l = Largest(1, 2, 2);
```

With those arguments, none of the conditions in your function will be `true`:

```
if (a > b && a > c) {           // 1 > 2 is false
    return a;
}
else if (a < b && b > c) {      // 1 < 2 is true, but 2 > 2 is false
    return b;
}
else if (a < c && c > b) {      // 1 < 2 is true, but 2 > 2 is false
    return c;
}
```

... so the function will go to the end *without* returning an `int` with undefined behavior as a result.

A simple fix:

```cpp
int Largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    return std::max(std::max(a, b), c); 
}
```

or

```cpp
int Largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    return std::max({a,b,c});
}
```

or more generic:

```cpp
template<class... Args>
auto Largest(Args&&... args) {
    return std::max({std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

Comment: Or `return std::max({a, b, c});`.

Comment: @NathanPierson Good idea. Added that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

@TedLyngmo's answer explains the source of your problem, as well as the proper solution using the standard library.

Adding this answer in case you need to implement the logic by yourself (for educational or some other reason):

```
int Largest(int a, int b, int c) 
{
    if (a >= b && a >= c) 
    {
        return a;  // none are larger than a
    }
    if (b >= a && b >= c) 
    {
        return b;  // none are larger than b
    }
    // If we got here then c is the largest:
    return c;
}
```

[Godbolt - demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qoaPWeaG9)

Note that I used `<=` instead of `<`, to handle cases where some of the values are the same.